# odd result converting XML to JSON

Tags: json, xml, data-conversion

I get an odd result when converting XML to JSON. I am using `JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode()`:

```
    XmlNodeList requestNode = xmlDocument.GetElementsByTagName("root","*");

    XmlNode objNode = requestNode[0];

    string json = JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode(objNode);
```

If my nodes include a namespace prefix and URL, the `JsonConvert.SerializeXmlNode` comes back with odd looking JSON having attributes like :

```
{"prefix:Amount":{"@xmlns:prefix":"http://BLA","#text":"1000"}}.
```

I expect :

```
{"prefix:Amount": 100, etc etc.}
```

The XML am trying to convert looks something like:

```
<a:root>
<prefix:Amount xmlns:prefix="http://BLA>1000</prefix:Amount>
</a:root>
```

Comment: There isn't an exact correspondence between XML and JSON and therefore there is no "correct" way of doing the transformation. Every converter handles the mismatches in its own particular way. If it doesn't do it the way you would like it done, then try a different converter.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML is not well-formed: `xmlns:prefix="http://BLA` is missing a closing quote.